# regex - check for decimal(javascript)

Tags: javascript, regex

I got this expression from stackoverflow itself - `/^\d+(\.\d{0,9})?$/`.

It takes care of:

```
2
23
23.
25.3
25.4334
0.44
```

but fails on `.23`. Can that be added to the above expression, or something that would take care of all of them?

Comment: Do you care about false positives? If not a simple \.? at the beginning will do it.

Comment: You just need to change the first "+" to "*".  Plus sign means ONE(1) or more while star means NONE(0) or more.  This also doesn't take into account the plus(+) sign or minus(-) sign that can be in front of numbers.  That would be "[+-]?" or it might be "[\+\-]?" if they have special meaning inside of the brackets.  Then you also have the "e+10" stuff.

Answer (score 31):

This will capture every case you posted as well as .23

Limit to 9 decimal places

```
var isDecimal = string.match( /^(\d+\.?\d{0,9}|\.\d{1,9})$/ );
```

No decimal limits:

```
var isDecimal = string.match( /^(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)$/ );
```

Comment: Limit the decimal places to nine, and it's perfect.

Comment: SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(\d+\.?\d{0,9}|\.\d{1,9}$/: Unterminated group

Comment: @Kooilnc: My bad! I messed it up editing in the decimal limit of 9. Try now

Comment: @Ben: yep, but then again it will not capture `3.141592653589793238462643383279502884197169399375105820974` ;~)

Comment: @KooiInc - The OP's pattern imposes the 9-decimal-places limit. He doesn't mention the limit specifically, but it looks intentional.

Comment: @Ben - You may find that the `\d+\.?\d{0,9}` group is very resource-intensive. If the input starts with a lot of numerals, there may be a lot of backtracking when it decides which digits should be consumed by the `\d+` and which belong in the `\d{0,9}`.

Comment: This will also match 23. `/^(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)$/.test('23.')`

Comment: And it will match 23.-1 `/^(\d+\.?\d*|\.\d+)$/.test(2.-1)`

Comment: and what about negative values

Answer (score 2):

This covers all your examples, allows negatives, and enforces the 9-digit decimal limit:

```
/^[+-]?(?=.?\d)\d*(\.\d{0,9})?$/
```

Live demo: https://regexr.com/4chtk

To break that down:

```
[+-]?       # Optional plus/minus sign (drop this part if you don't want to allow negatives)
(?=.?\d)    # Must have at least one numeral (not an empty string or just `.`)
\d*         # Optional integer part of any length
(\.\d{0,9}) # Optional decimal part of up to 9 digits
```

Since both sides of the decimal point are optional, the `(?=.?\d)` makes sure at least one of them is present. So the number can have an integer part, a decimal part, or both, but not neither.

One thing I want to note is that this pattern allows `23.`, which was in your example. Personally, I'd call that an invalid number, but it's up to you. If you change your mind on that one, it gets a lot simpler ([demo](https://regexr.com/4chtb)):

```
/^[+-]?\d*\.?\d{1,9}$/
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this expression:

> `^\d*\.?\d*$`

Comment: It should be

^\d*\.?\d+$