# Allow decimal point to be entered while using NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a script for a calculator i'm making and it prevents people from entering letters or things other than numbers. I need to allow decimal points. How can i do this?

```
$("input[type=text]").keyup(function () {
        var number = parseFloat($(this).val());
        var inc = parseFloat($(this).attr("inc"));
        var newValue = number / inc;
        $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
              if(isNaN(newValue * parseFloat($(this).attr("inc"))))
                $(this).val(0);
              else
                $(this).val(newValue * parseFloat($(this).attr("inc")));
           });
  });
```

If you have a simple fix or a whole new chunk of code that does everything then please let me know.

I NEED to be able to have decimal points. For example: 3.22

[JSFiddle available here](http://jsfiddle.net/RX2sL/)

Comment: Yes i am using HTML 5

Comment: Why you converting the Inc attr twice inside if condition also... instead you can use  var inc right

Comment: In your case Problem is not in html ... jquery keyup event is parsing each value you entering including DOT also ...

Comment: You can try http://plugins.jquery.com/df-number-format/  or  http://www.texotela.co.uk/code/jquery/numeric/

Comment: That second one looks alright

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two ways to solve this problem:

1. You are updating current input box as well ( the one in which you are typing currently), that should be handled seperately from the rest. ** modified ** : http://jsfiddle.net/RX2sL/10/

   ```
      $("input[type=text]").keyup(function () {
      var number = parseFloat($(this).val());

       var inc = parseFloat($(this).attr("inc"));
       var newValue = number / inc;
       var curr = this;

       $("input[type=text]").each(function () {
             if(isNaN(newValue * parseFloat($(this).attr("inc"))))
         $(this).val(0);
               else {

                   if(this != curr){          
         $(this).val(newValue * parseFloat($(this).attr("inc")));
                   }
                   else{
                       /* handle currrent input box */
                   }

               }
                   });
           });
   ```
2. A better & more flexible way is to check the string against a valid decimal string RegExp on keyup event. [regex - check for decimal(javascript)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6285119/regex-check-for-decimaljavascript)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
$("input[type=number]").keyup(function () {
    var regexp = /^[-+]?[0-9]+(\.[0-9]+)?$/;
        var number = $(this).val();
    var s=regexp.test(number);
    //alert(s);
        var inc = parseFloat($(this).attr("inc"));
        var newValue = number / inc;

        $("input[type=number]").not($(this)).each(function () {
              if(!s)
      $(this).val(0);
    else
      $(this).val(newValue * parseFloat($(this).attr("inc")));
                });
        });
```

Comment: Doesn’t quite work. Works for the input 3.2 but then if you type another digit, the other fields remain unchanged.

Comment: Yeah, it bugs out. Is there a way to fix that?

Answer (score 0):

If you are using HTML5, there might be a simpler solution (I am assuming there a textbox that you expect a user to type in some number):

```
<input type="number" step="1" pattern="\d+"/>
```

Read more about this [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.number.html)

You can also control `min`, `max`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Why you mention **type="text"** in your html element anyway you going to get number in that input element then why?... If it is in number no need to parse it and inside each function you appending the result directly to the current input(so every time input value changes) i altered something so plz check that before applying

**HTML**

```
 <input type="number" inc="1" />
    <input type="number" inc="2" />
    <input type="number" inc="3" />
    <input type="number" inc="4" />
```

**JQUERY**

```
$("input[type=number]").keyup(function () {

        var number = $(this).val();
        var inc = parseFloat($(this).attr("inc"));
        var newValue = number / inc;

        $("input[type=number]").not($(this)).each(function () {
              if(isNaN(newValue * parseFloat($(this).attr("inc"))))
      $(this).val(0);
    else
      $(this).val(newValue * parseFloat($(this).attr("inc")));
                });
        });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/RX2sL/14/)